# Deploying create-react-app with NodeJs Backend on Azure

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, node-sass

I made a React app with npm create-react-app which uses NodeJS backend. I am trying to deploy on Azure through Visual Studio Code extension.

I did not build locally but put a script in scripts object in package.json (of root folder)

```
 "build": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
```

My server.js resolves routing to the react app like this:

```
app.use(express.static("client/build"));
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
});
```

After I configure app services, resorce plans etc and deploy to app in App Service i get

```
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 12.x
Found bindings for the following environments:
Windows 64-bit with Node.js 12.x
```

And my Files folder in App Service is empty ( has only hostingstart.html )

I tried removing node-sass and installing it again, I tried rebuilding it but nothing helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could check your node-sass version first：`npm ls node-sass`

Have a look at [Node-sass release URL](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases).

I think you have done the right operation by removing and reinstalling your package, make sure you run these command in the **root path** of your project.

```
    npm rebuild node-sass
    npm update

    npm uninstall node-sass
    npm install node-sass
```

Don't forget restart your project.